# Return type for botbuilder's "handleTeamsMessagingExtensionBotMessagePreviewSend()" method?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to implement a bot in Microsoft Teams that leverages the `botMessagePreview` in its response. I've go the edit working just fine, but can't figure out how you're supposed to respond when you send the message to the conversation using the `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionBotMessagePreviewSend()` method.

The point of calling this method is to post a reply to the conversation, which can be done using `context.sendActivity()`.

But the SDK indicates you must RETURN an object of type `MessagingExtensionActionResponse` back to Teams ([see source](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder/src/teamsActivityHandler.ts#L543-L548)). I've tried multiple combinations but every time Teams displays an error it isn't supported.

The only sample I can find that uses this method from MSFT doesn't return anything (and also triggers an error in Teams): https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/msgext-action-preview/nodejs/bots/teamsMessagingExtensionsActionPreviewBot.js#L50-L74

Any ideas how you can implement this scenario without an error?